Difference between clearfix and clear:both at the following element
I have floated some elements and to make the layout appear proper. I have two ways basically clear-fix and clear:both at the following element.
1)
.extra-float-container::after{
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}





footer {
    clear: both;
    background-color: #ff0;
    padding: 10px;
}

I can't able understand why there are two ways to that. Is there any special use-cases for each of them so that other option doesn't work?

clear: both on a following element causes the border-box of that element to be below the floats. clearfixes on the containing element cause the margin-box of the following element to be below the floats. Depending on the use case, you might want either one of these behaviours.

These two techniques achieve similar outcomes, with subtle differences. Personally if a simple clear: both works for a particular layout, then it would be my first choice. But there may be layouts for which the clearfix hack works better, in which case I would use that.
Here is a snippet which illustrates the differences.


div {
  border: 3px solid #4CAF50;
  padding: 5px;
}

.img1, .img2 {
  float: right;
}

.next {
  color: green; 
}

hr, .clear {
  clear: both;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

code {
  background: silver;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  border-bottom: 3px dashed orange;
}
<h2>Base case</h2>

<div>
  <img class="img1" src="https://picsum.photos/340" width="170" height="170">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet...
</div>

<p class="next">Next paragraph</p>

<hr>

<h2 style="clear:right">Use of clear: both</h2>
<p>You can add <code>clear: both</code> to an element to make sure it starts beneath any floats. Here I have applied it to the next paragraph. This is a simple CSS style, which does the job if applied correctly.</p>

<div>
  <img class="img2" src="https://picsum.photos/340" width="170" height="170">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet...
</div>

<p class="next clear">Next paragraph cleared</p>

<hr>

<h2>With clearfix hack</h2>
<p>The clearfix hack <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp">as described here</a>, is used on the parent of the floated element. It uses <code>clear: both</code> as well, but adds a couple of extra styles to make the parent container grow to contain the float. If this is more suitable for your use case, then use it.</p>

<div class="clearfix">
  <img class="img2" src="https://picsum.photos/340" width="170" height="170">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet...
</div>

<p class="next">Next paragraph</p>




If you need the floated element's parent to grow to contain the float, then you need clearfix. Otherwise you can just use the simple method.

clearfix is a add-on class with clear: both property to clear floating of an element.
While clear: both itself a property to clear floating of both side of an element.
Float was used when there were no flex or grid properties available.
You can use flex or grid layout to achieve your design.
Hope, this will help.

Thanks for the answer. but i also need to know the whether there is any special for using clearfix as well as the only clear property in the following element

Please bear in mind that clearfix is an add-on class created to clear the floating property of an element.
While clear: both is property itself used in clearfix to clear the floating property of an element.
Clearfix is used to avoid collision or meeting of elements when there is not requirement.
You can refer https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float_clear.asp for better understanding.

You should not refer to w3school as a sole reference. As a matter of fact, w3school is quite outdated and where largely incorrect 6 years ago. Any reputable documentation would be the official documentation such as MDN WebDocs and w3.org.

@tacoshy Got it.  Thanks for the heads up.
